# Magento2 on docker css and js don't load

Tags: magento2, css, docker

I installed magento using composer:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
```

and load sample data.
It works pretty fine on localhost.

I created dockerfile and docker-compose for magento:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER xxxx

RUN apt-get -qqy update

RUN apt-get -qqy install apache2 \
        php \
        mysql-client \
        libapache2-mod-php \
        php-pear \
        php-mcrypt \
        php-gd \
        php-curl \
        php-mysql \
        php-dom \
        php-xml \
        php-xsl \
        php-mbstring \
        php-intl \
        php-zip \
        php-cli \
        php-cgi \
        curl \
        git \
        nano \
        vim \
        htop
RUN apt-get -qqy install nodejs npm
RUN apt-get -qqy install php-fpm

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

ADD ./20-mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
ADD ./20-mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini


RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY ./magento2.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento2.conf
#RUN rm -f /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

#COPY xdebug-enabler.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/

RUN php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"

COPY ./apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN a2enmod php7.0
RUN service apache2 restart


WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 9001
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

magento2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html
       ServerName magento2test.localhost
       <Directory /var/www/html>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

apache2.conf:

```
#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
    allowOverride  all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

and finaly docker-compose:

```
mageweb:
  build: docker-files/apache-xdebug
  command: rm -f /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
  command: apachectl -D FOREGROUND
  ports:
    - "8081:8081"
    - "80:80"
    - "9001:9001"
    - "443:443"
  volumes:
    -  ./project/:/var/www/html/
```

Now it is only one image cause im using remote mysql and I will add more images later.

Anyway I'm able to build and up docker.
I'm able to install and setup magento.
Of course I tried flush all cache, and done all of those comands (using docker exec -it container_name bash:

```
php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
php bin/magento module:enable --all
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

But style.css and some js are not loading property:
[image]

system.log:

```
[2016-11-17 07:27:39] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_2ae0e2a835d549823c9720ea0833000d3 and handles default, catalog_category_view, catalog_category_view_type_default, catalog_category_view_type_default_without_children, catalog_category_view_id_39: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-11-17 07:27:39] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_2a7ccd8094436548b564a588f6303121c and handles 2columns-left: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-11-17 07:27:40] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_26f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

Do You have any ideas hot can I fix it?

Comment: Also I cant appy permisions for project on run container. It won' t apply. May it be because of Windows?

Comment: Have you enabled Developer mode? Check if chmod settings are right!

Comment: Hey its 5 years old topic :d developer mode was enabled with correct permissions ;) But now I just dont remember what the problem was

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands below to enable the developer mode, clean cache and all the routine process, these commands resolved this issue here and other 90% of the cases.

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"
mage deploy:mode:set developer
chmod -R 777 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage cache:disable && 
mage cache:clean &
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy ; mage setup:static-content:deploy -f;
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 777 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer but it didn't help. Solution for me was fix docker file a bit. Ill upload it later

Comment: what was your fix? same issue here..